# Simultaneus development in Visual Studio and a Linux IDE

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linux

I am trying to get started with an existing open source project ([QuantLib](http://quantlib.org/index.shtml)) using Linux operating system. However it seems that most developers use Visual Studio (judging from the project files committed with the source).

Which Linux C++ IDE would be most compatible with VS project files? Is there a way to import/export them, so that I don't have to create my own projects from scratch (and update them every time someone adds a new file)?

EDIT: Its all unmanaged code

Comment: Looking at the SVN repository it is already set up for development using make. Just read the file name README or INSTALL one will have full instructions.

Comment: @Martin, yeah, I figured out how to compile it. However I would like to use an IDE for convenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, the best method for doing dual-development on Linux & Windows is to throw away the existing Visual Studio project files and, instead, use CMake to generate the platform-specific build environment. It's capable of outputting Nmake makefiles (for command-line Windows builds), Visual Studio projects, and Linux makefiles. The documentation leaves a bit to be desired but once you have it up and running, it's very easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

The [FAQ](http://quantlib.org/faq.shtml#General%20questions3) provides installation instructions for MinGW. It seems that there is a GNU Makefile included, so you don't need to mess with Visual Studio project files.

Answer (score 0):

Aparantly they they only build on MAC and Windows.

Instructions here: http://quantlib.org/install/macosx.shtml

But since MAC is basically BSD Unix it should be identical (or with little trouble) to get it up and running on Linux.

The following should work (though you may need to look at the configure options)

```
1) Install Boost.
2) ./configure
3) make
```

Answer (score -2):

You'll definitely want to check out Mono, it might be just what you're looking for: http://monodevelop.com/